# Basing a logical argument on status of initialization of variable

Tags: c, syntax, logic, c99

Say we defie num somewhere (local variable)

```
int num;
```

then, if initialized, say :

```
num = 420;
```

we do something, if not, we don't.

Is this possible in C99 / c overall? can't find it in the manual.

Comment: Do you depend your action on the initialization itsself or the value of `num`?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to programatically detect whether a variable is initialized or not? If so, the answer is no. In C, you, the programmer, needs to keep track of it.

Comment: @CoolGuy yeah that's what I was asking

Comment: @Downvoter on the initialization itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just write

```
num = 420;
```

and then try to depend your action on the fact if `num` has been initialized, then no, you cannot do that.
The reason is that C doesn't store the information, whether a variable has been initialized or not, anywhere at runtime. Only the compiler knows that at compile time.
Checking if `num == 420` wouldn't work either. If it's an automatic variable and hasn't been initialized it's value is indeterminate and might very well be `420` without explicit initialization. Accessing that variable without initialization is undefined anyway.

What you could do is to depend the initialization on some condition, like this:

```
if (cond)
    num = 420;
```

Now, `!cond` is equivalent to "`num` has not been initialized." You can depend any further code on that condition `cond`, and it'll only execute if `cond` is true, which is equivalent to "`num` has been initialized with `420`."